# Is it possible to switch between executables using command line

Tags: windows, cmd, focus, executable, taskmanager

I have on my computer a lot of running executable , something like 30-40.
So when I want to focus/switch to another executable, I do: ALT+TAB or search them in task-manager and click twice.
But I feel it takes from me a lot of time on searching the executable I need.

Lets imagine that one of the executable is calc.exe .

Is it possible to go to command line or WIN-KEY+R, and write something like :"go to calc.exe" ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I see here will be to use 3rd party SW to emulate the typing of some keys:

http://toppersworld.com/10-autohotkey-alternatives-to-create-your-own-macros-and-apps/

or call *sendkeys.bat "App1" ""*  using this: https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/sendKeys.bat

Comment: I think I didn't understand your answer. The first link, I understand I need to do a macro for example CTRL+C+A+L+C and it OPEN a calculator. But I want it not to OPEN calculator but to switch to the running calc.exe. So the second solution closer to what I'm looking for, because it change the focus to calc.exe. But I don't want to send any keys. I just want to focus on calc.exe like You do ALT+TAB. But instead ALT+TAB I want it in "command line" , because I want it to focus FAST as possible. Maybe i didn't explain myself well in the question...

Comment: With the command I don't see a  solution for focus in another window, that's why my suggestion is to emulate alt tab with 3rd party keys generation